# Short Key for Generate String From Layout XML

Tags: android, xml

I have seen that there some short key for generate new string, dimens value etc from Layout XML file...But I don't remember it.

Example I have input new dimes in Layout XML called time_padding. its showing red error that there no any value called time_padding in dimens file....Now I want generate its from xml so it can be handy for fast work. Let me know if someone know it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Alt + Enter` then "extract string" to create new string under `resources.string`.

You can do the same for extracting `dimesions` as well.

[image]

Comment: ...its working fine...can You please tell me for dimen value also. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you  :)

Answer (score -1):

In android, the `layout parameters` depends on the type of layout.

For example:

Suppose you are using `Relative layout` then you can use

`android:layout_alignParentBottom
android:layout_alignParentEnd
android:layout_alignParentLeft
android:layout_alignParentRight` etc

But these parameters are not available for the `Linear layout`.

So, please mention which `layout` you are using.